# What can I substitute for the egg used to seal egg rolls?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, vegan

I would like to make a vegan "egg roll". In a normal egg roll, the filling is cooked and then placed in a wrapper, which is folded and sealed with egg before frying. I know how to make substitutions for the filling to make a vegan end product, but what can I substitute for the egg sealant?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flour paste. Mix flour with water and a bit of salt. Go for a thick glaze-like consistency, and use it instead of the egg. Give it at least 10 minutes to hold before frying, and try to hold the edges closed with tongs when initially frying.

Comment: Might not even need the flour -- I've had good luck in the past just using a bowl of water that I dip a finger into and wet down the edge before I finish rolling.  (I suspect that this might be affected by how fresh your wrappers are, though)

Comment: Flour paste is used in many spring roll recipes as a sealer, so it is not even an offbeat technique.

Answer (score 1):

Cornflour mixed with a bit of water works great, and it's gluten free as well.